# c++ Create time remaining estimate when data calcs get progressively longer?

Tags: c++, math, progress-bar, trendline

I'm adding items to a list, so each insert takes just a bit longer than the last (this is a requirement, assume you can't change that).  I've manually timed a sample dataset on MY computer but I want a generalized way to predict the time on any computer, and given ANY dataset size.

In my flailing around trying to figure this out, what i have collected is a vector, 100 long, of "how long 1/100th the sample data" took.  So in my example data set i have 237,965 objects, which means in the vector of times i collected, each bucket tells how long it took to add 2,379 items.

Here's a [link to the sample data](https://pastebin.com/tUdqJVJD) of 100 items. So you can see the first 2k items took about 8 seconds, and the last 2k items took about 101 seconds.  All together, if you add all the time, that's 4,295 seconds or about 1 hr 11 minutes.

So my question is, given this data set, and using it for future predictions, how do i estimate the remaining time when adding different size data?

In more flailing, i made some plots, wondering if it could help. First plot is just the raw data on a log graph:

[image: raw data]

I then made a 2nd data set based on first, this time showing accumulated time, rather than just the time for the current slice, and plotted that on a linear graph:

[image: linear graph]

Notice the lovely trend line formula? That MUST be something that i just need to somehow plug into my code but i can't for the life of me figure out how.

Should i have instead gathered the data into time-slices and not index-slices?  ie: i KNOW this data takes 1:10 to load, so take snapshots every 1/100th of that duration, instead of snapshotting every 1/100th of the data set?

Or HOW do i figure this out?

the function I need to write has this API:

```
CFTimeInterval      get_estimated_end_time(int maxI, int curI, CFTimeInterval elapsedT);
```

so given only those three variables (maxI, curI, and elapsedT), and knowing the trend line formula from above, i need to return "duration until maxI" (seconds).

Any ideas?

### Update:

well it seems after much futzing around, i can just do this (note "LERP" is just linear interpolate):

```
#define         kDataSetMax     237965

double          FunctionX(int in_x)
{
    double      _x(LERP(0, 100, in_x, 0, i_maxI));

    double      resultF =
          (0.32031139888898874  * math_square(_x))
        + (9.609731568497784    * _x)
        - (7.527252350031663);

    if (resultF <= 1) {
        resultF = 1;
    }

    return resultF;
}


CFTimeInterval  get_estimated_end_time(int maxI, int curI, CFTimeInterval elapsedT)
{
    CFTimeInterval      endT(FunctionX(maxI));

    return remainingT;
}
```

But that means i'm just ***ignoring*** `curI` and `elapsedT`??  That doesn't seem... right?  What am I missing?

### Footnotes:

```
#define     LERP(to_min, to_max, from, from_min, from_max)  \
    ((from_max) == (from_min) ? from :                      \
    (double)(to_min) + ((double)((to_max) - (to_min))       \
        * ((double)((from) - (from_min))                    \
        / (double)((from_max) - (from_min)))))

#define     LERP_PERCENT(from, from_max) \
    LERP(0.0f, 1.0f, from, 0.0f, from_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FunctionX` is most of the way there. It's currently calculating `expectedTimeToReachMaxIOnMyMachine`. What you need to do is figure out how much slower the current time is relative to the expected on your machine to reach this same point, and then extrapolate that same ratio to the maximum time.

```
CFTimeInterval get_estimated_end_time(int maxI, int curI, CFTimeInterval elapsedT) {
    //calculate how long we expected it to take to reach this point
    CFTimeInterval expectedTimeToReachCurrentIOnMyMachine = FunctionX(curI);
    //calculate how much slower we are than the expectation
    //if this machine is faster, the math still works out.
    double slowerThanExpectedByRatio 
            = double(elapsedT) / expectedTimeToReachCurrentIOnMyMachine;
    
    //calculate how long we expected to reach the max
    CFTimeInterval expectedTimeToReachMaxIOnMyMachine = FunctionX(maxI);
    //if we continue to be the same amount slower, we'll reach the max at:
    CFTimeInterval estimatedTimeToReachMaxI 
            = expectedTimeToReachMaxIOnMyMachine * slowerThanExpectedByRatio;
    return estimatedTimeToReachMaxI;
}
```

Note that a smart implementation can cache and reuse `expectedTimeToReachMaxIOnMyMachine` and not calculate it every time.

Basically this assumes that after doing X% of the work, we can calculate how much slower we were than the *expected* curve, and assume we will stay approximately that same amount slower than the expected curve.

In the example below, the expected time taken is the blue line.  At 4000 elements, we see that the expected time on your machine was 8,055,826, But the actual time taken on this machine was 10,472,573, which is 30% higher (`slowerThanExpectedByRatio=1.3`).  At that point, we can extrapolate that we'll probably remain 30% higher throughout the entire process (the purple line). So if the total expected time on your machine for 10000 elements was 32,127,229, then our total estimated time on this machine for 10000 will be 41,765,398 (30% higher)
[image]

Comment: this is good, a very good start, but it's not accounting for the curve i don't think?  ie: it's better in that it adheres to "under-promise, over-deliver", which is GOOD, but it's not as accurate as i was hoping it could be. eg: with the original database, it starts off saying it'll take over 2 hours (it should nail the 1h 10min, cuz the data is BASED on this db). on a smaller db, it says it'll take 10 mins, but ends up taking 3.  Is this extrapolating linearly? shouldn't the extrapolation be based on the curve?

Comment: `FunctionX` is already handling the curve. `slowerThanExpectedByRatio` extrapolating linearly based on _deviance from the curve_. I'll add more details.

Comment: then shouldn't we get a perfectly accurate prediction when going over the original dataset?

Comment: @DavidM.Cotter: The real world is complicated. On one cpu, multiplication might be faster, and on another division might be faster. One machine might have a virus scan running in the background using cpu unpredictably. One machine might have photoshop open, so the OS has to pause your process to shuffle memory around. One machine might be fragging the hard drive, causing any storage access to be super slow. And all of these might change mid-run. So no estimate is going to be "perfectly" accurate.  The algorithm here will effectively adjust on the fly though.

Comment: no i mean, on the same computer running the same dataset, i get the exact same duration for the ops in the end, but your version of the calc function's end time estimate is way off.. shouldn't the function just return the same end time as the original data showed, when given the same exact data again? nothing else is running on the computer at the time, so it's a pure environment

Comment: @DavidM.Cotter: Hm . Still looks right to me. Oh, Now I understand your first comment. With the original database it overestimates early on, and with a small database it also overestimates early on? How early? And how accurate is `FunctionX(curI)` early in the dataset?

Comment: @DavidM.Cotter: One possibility is that the cpu is changing speeds. Most of the time, a computer is idle, and so the cpu runs super slow to save power/heat. When the calculation starts, this code will accurately estimate the time as slow, but as the calculation continues, the cpu will get faster and faster until it reaches max speed, so then the estimate will drop slowly over time until the calculation ends. Maybe that's what you're seeing?

Comment: as i said, it takes 1hr 10min for the data to be loaded. the time estimate function as you wrote it estimates about 2 hours 10 minutes, and stays "off" by about that much the entire time, counting down by about 2 seconds per second. this is obviously wrong.  same with a smaller data set.

Comment: and wouldn't this be "more correct":?
` // if we continue to be the same amount slower, we'll reach the max at:`  
` CFTimeInterval  endT = expectedTimeToReachMaxIOnMyMachine * slowerThanExpectedByRatio;`  
` `  
` return endT - elapsedT;`

Comment: @DavidM.Cotter: Oh! My get_estimated_end_time returns the estimated _total_ time.  If you want it to return the estimated _remaining_ time, then yes, then you have to subtract `elapsedT`